# Linker error : undefined reference to _fbss

Tags: linux, gcc, compiler-construction, linker-scripts

I'm sucessfully building pulp-riscv-gnu-toolchain from this [this](https://github.com/pulp-platform/pulp-riscv-gnu-toolchain)

But when I try to compile my simple source code with builded compiler,
error occured.

My command is `riscv32-unknown-elf-g++ -o hello hello.cpp`

Error message is `/home/jskim/test_toolchains_lib/gcc/riscv32-unknown-elf/7.1.1/../../../../riscv32-unknown-elf/bin/ld : cannot open linker script file riscv.ld : No such file or directory`

So I try with this command `riscv32-unknown-elf-g++ -o main main.cpp -T /home/jskim/test_toolchains/riscv32-unknown-elf-ld/lib/ldscripts/elf32lriscv.x`

But following error occured : `/home/jskim/test_toolchains/lib/gcc/riscv32-unknown-elf/7.1.1/../../../../riscv32-unknown-elf/lib/crt0.o: In function '.L0': (.text+0x10):undefined reference to '_fbss' collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

I'm using CentOS 7.6 and I try build this pulp-gcc with gcc 4.8.5 and 7.3.1 but both shows me same error. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolve the problem in this way.

[Actually Here is the solution.](https://github.com/pulp-platform/pulpino/issues/240)[image]

I'm not accurate but I think the problem is that the name is not matched.
crt0, which seems to be the helper of start riscv processor has this line `la a0 _fbss` just basically linker can recognize this if _fbss is replaced with _edata. So i edit the assembly file which is located at `pulp-riscv-gnu-toolchain/riscv-newlib/libgloss/riscv/` And rebuild the gnu toolchain. And execute your compiler with -T option like `riscv32-unknown-elf-g++ -o main main.cpp -T /home/jskim/test_toolchains/riscv32-unknown-elf-ld/lib/ldscripts/elf32lriscv.x`

This is the easiest solution as I think.